# How can I implement a search functionality in .NET MAUI using SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, maui

I want to implement search functionality to filter through all my projects for a storybook illustrator company. This is how I get all the projects to show in my front-end, but I want to search for a specific project by name and ID. Any ideas?

```
[RelayCommand]
       public async void GetProjectList()
       {
           Projects.Clear();
           var projectList = await _projectService.GetProjectList();
           if (projectList?.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (var project in projectList)
               {
                   Projects.Add(project);
               }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple relaycommand to bind the function to a button press after search, to search for an item make a variable and set it equal to the list of projects then just do a simple where statement setting a value to the specific item in the table you need like an Id or first name then set it to Contains where the variable you want to search for , this will be the one in the entry inside and turn the result into a list that can be displayed on the View.

```
[RelayCommand]
public async void ProjectSearchItems()
{
    var projectList = await _projectService.GetProjectList();
    var searchedName = projectList.Where(value => value.ProjectName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("//var from frontend searchbar")).ToList();
    var searchedID = projectList.Where(value => value.ProjectID.ToString().Contains("//var from frontend searchbar")).ToList();

    //Clearing previous projects
    Projects.Clear();
    foreach (var project in searchedName)
    {
        //add Projectname searched to List
        Projects.Add(project);
    }
    foreach (var project in searchedID)
    {
        //add ProjectID searched to List
        Projects.Add(project);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).